# App passed the Instruments leak check but crashes after running for about 20 mins due to memory issues

Tags: swift, swiftui

I tested my app with Instruments and found no leaks but memory increases every time any value is updated and My app is updated every 0.5 second in multiple places. After running for about 20 mins, My app crashed and i got "Terminated due to memory issue" message.

I tried to find out which place cause this issue and ItemView seems to be causing the problem. I created a code snippet and the test result is below.
Please explain what's wrong with my code.

Thanks for any help!

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var laserPower: Float = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ItemView(
                title: "Laser Power",
                value: $laserPower,
                unit: "W",
                callback: { (newValue) in
                    print("setPower")
                    //Api.setPower(watts: newValue)
                }
            )
        }
        .onAppear {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: true) { _ in
                //Memory increases every time the laserPower's value is updated. 
                laserPower = Float(Int.random(in: 1..<160) * 10)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    
    let title: String
    @Binding var value: Float
    let unit: String
    let callback: (_ newValue: Float) -> Void
    
    @State private var stringValue = ""
    @State private var isEditingValue = false
    @State var editingValue: Float = 0
    
    func getStringValue(from value: Float) -> String {
        return String(format: "%.1f", value)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            HStack {
                Text(title)
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack {
                TextField(
                    "",
                    text: $stringValue,
                    onEditingChanged: { editingChanged in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if !editingChanged {
                                if stringValue.contain(pattern: "^-?\\d+\\.\\d$") {
                                    editingValue = Float(stringValue)!
                                } else if stringValue.contain(pattern: "^-?\\.\\d$") {
                                    stringValue = "0.\(stringValue.split(separator: ".", omittingEmptySubsequences: false)[1])"
                                    editingValue = Float(stringValue)!
                                } else if stringValue.contain(pattern: "^-?\\d+\\.?$") {
                                    stringValue = "\(stringValue.split(separator: ".", omittingEmptySubsequences: false)[0]).0"
                                    editingValue = Float(stringValue)!
                                } else {
                                    stringValue = getStringValue(from: value)
                                }
                                callback(Float(getStringValue(from: editingValue))!)
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                                    isEditingValue = false
                                }
                            } else {
                                isEditingValue = true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    onCommit: {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            callback(Float(getStringValue(from: editingValue))!)
                        }
                    }
                )
                    .font(.title)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(4)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke())
                Text(unit)
                    .padding(5)
            }
        }
        .padding(10)
        .onReceive(Just(stringValue)) { newValue in
            if newValue.contain(pattern: "^-?\\d+\\.\\d?$") {
                return
            }
            var filtered = newValue.filter { "0123456789.-".contains($0) }
            let split = filtered.split(separator: ".", omittingEmptySubsequences: false)
            if (split.count > 1 && String(split[1]).count > 1) || split.count > 2 {
                let dec = split[1]
                filtered = "\(split[0]).\(dec.isEmpty ? "" : String(dec[dec.startIndex]))"
            }
            self.stringValue = filtered
        }
        .onChange(of: value) { _ in
            if !isEditingValue {
                stringValue = getStringValue(from: self.value)
                editingValue = value
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            stringValue = getStringValue(from: value)
            editingValue = value
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    func contain(pattern: String) -> Bool {
        guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpression.Options()) else {
            return false
        }
        return regex.firstMatch(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.count)) != nil
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Memory report:
[image: Memory report]

Instruments report:
[image]

Comment: Put all the non UI specific code in a ViewModel that is an ObservableObject your View is doing too much

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think it has anything to do with memory issues

Comment: Can you figure out _which_ objects are allocated? (using the profiler or the memory graph)

Comment: sorry i don't understand the information in the graph T_T

Comment: I ran your code for 4 hours. All levels have been stable. CPU @2%, Memory is 9.2 or 3. Xcode 13RC, iOS 15 simulator.

Comment: You're right. It worked fine with iOS 15 simulator. My test was in iOS 14.5 device and simulator.